# What is alternative of ELT() function in Postgresql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

In MySQL, you can use the ELT() function to return an item from a specified position in a list.

How to find same in Postgresql

--- IN MYSQL

```
SELECT ELT(3, 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse') AS 'Result';
```

--- Result ----------

```
 Horse
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an array:

```
select (array['Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse'])[3];
```

If you need a function for compatibility reasons:

```
create or replace function elt(int, variadic text[])
returns text language sql immutable as $$
    select $2[$1]
$$;

select elt(3, 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse') AS "Result";
```

Update. The Postgres equivalent of `find_in_set()` (slightly improved version of @PavelStehule function from the comments):

```sql
create or replace function find_in_set(text, text)
returns int immutable strict as $$
    select coalesce(array_position(string_to_array($2, ','), $1::text), 0)
$$ language sql;
```

Test the functions in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/FpzzbjKt)

Comment: what is alternative of find_in_set in postgresql ?                                                   
   select find_in_SET(12,'14,12,13,15,18,16,15,12')

Comment: @Neal - `create or replace function find_in_set(text, text) returns int as $$ select coalesce(array_position(string_to_array($2, ','), $1::text), 1) $$ language sql;`

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use a `CASE` expression in Postgres.  Replace:

```
ELT(col, 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse')
```

with:

```
SELECT
    CASE col WHEN 1 THEN 'Cat'
             WHEN 2 THEN 'Dog'
             WHEN 3 THEN 'Horse' END AS animal
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: But I need the dynamic query . so how to handle.